# Cannot read from a texture when binding to GL_TEXTURE0

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm learning to use OpenGL in my free time, and I'm working on deferred rendering right now. I've been stuck on this problem for a few weeks. When I bind my diffuse texture to GL_TEXTURE0, each pixel in the texture is (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f). When I switch it to GL_TEXTURE3 it works. Where should I be looking to debug this problem?

I will post the draw call for the rendering below.

The entire source code is in this repository:
https://github.com/DanielSmithMichigan/OpenGLExperimentation

The act of writing and reading from different textures happens in here:
https://github.com/DanielSmithMichigan/OpenGLExperimentation/blob/master/OpenGlTest6/Defer.h

The draw call:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

// if I switch GL_TEXTURE0 to GL_TEXTURE3
// and diffuseUniform << 0 to diffuseUniform << 3
// then it will work
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, diffuseTexture);
*diffuseUniform << 0;

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, positionTexture);
*positionUniform << 1;

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, normalsTexture);
*normalsUniform << 2;

*ambientColorUniform << objects->ambientLight->color;
*lightColorUniform << objects->sun->color;
*lightDirectionUniform << objects->sun->direction;
*cameraPositionUniform << objects->camera->position;
*specularColorUniform << objects->sun->color;
*specularPowerUniform << 5.0f;

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
glVertex3f((float)width, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
glVertex3f((float)width, (float)height, 0.0f);
glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
glVertex3f(0.0f, (float)height, 0.0f);
glEnd();
```

Comment: what if you use GL_TEXTURE1 with uniform = 0 ?

Comment: Thanks for the response - Did not work... the texture ended up covering the whole screen. It seems the active texture has to match the uniform.

But I did find that I can move diffuse to 1, position to 2, and normals to 3, and that will work. I still don't know why 0 won't work, though

Comment: I put why it works in my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that in the files Mesh.h and Grid.h, I was binding a sampler to index 0 (GL_TEXTURE0). This sampler was still bound by the time I was trying to bind/read my diffuse texture on index 0.

The solution was to use glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0) and glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) before I started my geometry pass, and the opposite glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0) and glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) after it ended.

Then in the draw call for my deferred rendering object, I use glBindSampler(0, 0).

As far as I can tell, all 5 functions mentioned above were necessary.

The fix for this problem is in commit hash d60fec483e896971304f5f9f24c4bd0f10fe48fe for anyone who needs more information.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to say GL_TEXTURE1 with uniform = 1

Because I doubted a texture you made before the diffuse texture using **glGenTextures(1, &depthBuffer)** but I don't know why you made its name **depthBuffer** depthbuffer must be one of RBOs not a texture.

Anyway,

> the default value of glactivetexture() is GL_TEXTURE0

You didn't call glactivetexture(GL_TEXTURE0) before you called glbindtexture(depthBuffer) although because the default value is GL_TEXTURE0, **you are using GL_TEXTURE0 already for the depthBuffer** .

Comment: Thank you for answering! I don't think this is correct though.

I did find a solution to the problem, but it wasn't this. Removing the depth buffer, or using glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE7) before creating it did not fix the problem. Furthermore, the documentation for glBindTexture says "When a texture is bound to a target, the previous binding for that target is automatically broken."

I will describe the fix and what was happening in my own reply to my post.